# Is it possible to add an icon in the title of a JustGage graph?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, justgage

I am making a graph using [JustGage](http://www.justgage.com/). Here is my javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var g1 = new JustGage({
    id: "g1", 
    value: getRandomInt(0, 100), 
    min: 0,
    max: 300,
    title: "font awesome icon here"
  });
};
```

Is it possible to get a [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icon in the title? I tried adding the unicode (&#xf023), and that didn't work. I also tried copying and pasting in the icon and that just resulted in a square.

I want the icon above the graph, where there is currently a square:

[image]

Here's the demo code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Auto-adjust</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #g1, #g2, #g3 {
      width:20em; height:15em;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 1em;
    }

    p {
      display: block;
      width: 450px;
      margin: 2em auto;
      text-align: left;
    }
    </style>

<script src="resources/js/raphael.2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/justgage.1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var g1, g2, g3;

  window.onload = function(){
    var g1 = new JustGage({
      id: "g1", 
      value: getRandomInt(0, 100), 
      min: 0,
      max: 300,
      title: "trying to get font awesome here"
    });

    var g2 = new JustGage({
      id: "g2", 
      value: getRandomInt(0, 100), 
      min: 0,
      max: 300, 
      title: "trying to get font awesome here"
    });

    var g3 = new JustGage({
      id: "g3", 
      value: getRandomInt(0, 100), 
      min: 0,
      max: 300
      title: "trying to get font awesome here"
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      g1.refresh(getRandomInt(50, 300));
      g2.refresh(getRandomInt(50, 300));          
      g3.refresh(getRandomInt(0, 300));
    }, 2500);
  };
</script>

</head>
 <body>    
    <div id="g1"></div>
    <div id="g2"></div>
    <div id="g3"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/layoku/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Did you try to use the backslash `\f023`?

Comment: Yes, that didn't work sadly.

Comment: `document.title = "\uf023"`

Comment: @Mia Could you post the HTML/CSS and JS needed to load this Graph?

Comment: Do you use the font in other places? And it works? I think you didn't set the font property. Remember to use `font-family: FontAwesome`.

Comment: I added the html, css, and js. I am linking to Font Awesome like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> in the <head> of the document. I have used the icons in other places and it has worked fine.

Comment: BTW, you're missing a comma after the third occurance of this line `max: 300`. You should check your JS with http://jshint.com/.

Comment: Tip 2: Your meta tag should look like this: `<meta charset="utf-8">`, just like [h5bp](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.html#L4) does it.

Comment: Tip 3: Stick all your `<script>`s right before your closing `</body>` tag. Your page will render faster and you can stop using `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1):

One method to use Font awsome directly as the title is to make the Gauge title color the same as the background color so its transparent and append into the Gauge the Font. Some css styling for the position is needed to place it at the center top

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/8uybzx0e/

**Code**

```
 var g1 = new JustGage({
  id: "g1", 
  value: getRandomInt(0, 100), 
  min: 0,
  max: 300,
  title: "Title",
  titleFontColor: "white"

});

$("#g1").append('<i class="fontaw fa fa-user-plus"></i>')
```

**Css**

```
.fontaw {
position:absolute;
z-index:9999;
top:50px;
left:33%;
font-size:30px;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was in  the default styling in justgage.1.0.1.js. I had to go into that file and change the font-family from Arial to Font Awesome:

```
   // title
  this.txtTitle = this.canvas.text(this.params.titleX, this.params.titleY,this.config.title);
  this.txtTitle. attr({
    "font-size":this.params.titleFontSize,
    "font-weight":"bold",
    "font-family":"FontAwesome", //changed this line
    "fill":this.config.titleFontColor,
    "fill-opacity":"1"         
  });
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If you consider your own answer as valid, please, mark it as valid! Anyway I recommend you to see @TasosAnastasiou answer, which looks an efficient way to achieve it.

Comment: It won't let me mark it as valid for 20 hours, after that I will.